# Не могу разобраться с System.nanoTime()

Tags: java

Есть задание:

> Implement the ability to generate a pseudo-random secret number of the
>   given length. If the given length is greater than 10, print a message
>   and don't generate the number.
>
> We suggest you use the following algorithm to generate the numbers.
>
> ```
> final class SecretGenerator {
>
>     public static void main(final String[] args) {
>         long pseudoRandomNumber = System.nanoTime();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This code saves the nanoseconds since some fixed time to the
>   pseudoRandomNumber variable. Now we can assume that this is a random
>   number. So you can generate a secret number by iterating the
>   pseudoRandomNumber in reverse order and adding unique digits in the
>   secret number. If the pseudoRandomNumber lacks the required amount of
>   unique digits, call System.nanoTime() again and try to generate the
>   secret number again until you get a satisfactory number.

Перевод:

Реализовать возможность генерации псевдо-случайного секретного числа заданной длины. Если заданная длина числа больше 10, то вывести сообщение и не генерировать число.

Мы предлагаем вам использовать следующий алгоритм для генерации чисел.

```
final class SecretGenerator {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        long pseudoRandomNumber = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

Этот код сохраняет количество наносекунд с некоторого фиксированного времени в переменную `pseudoRandomNumber`. 
Мы можем предположить, что это случайное число. Таким образом вы можете генерировать секретное число путем итерирования по переменной `pseudoRandomNumber` в обратном порядке и добавления к нему уникальных цифр.

Если `pseudoRandomNumber` не будет хватать необходимого количества цифр, тогда снова вызовите System.nanoTime() и сгенерируйте новое секретное число. Повторяйте так до тех пор, пока не получите необходимый результат.

Не могу понять, как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Comment: 1) Переведите задание на русский язык; 2) укажите, в чём конкретно возникает проблема, что вы уже сделали

Comment: Часть проблемы в том, что я не очень знаю английский) Соответственно, не уверен, что до конца правильно въехал в задание. Как я понял, мне нужно сделать генератор случайных чисел на основе метода System.nanoTime(), но как точно его использовать, мне не ясно. Хотел бы увидеть мнение более опытных товарищей)

Comment: translate.google.ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я расшифровал.

Нужно разбить число на десятичные знаки и перебирать их добавляя к результату. Если знак уже встречался, то пропустить. Если не набралось необходимое количество знаков, то повторить.

Вот откуда взялось ограничение на длину в 10 символов.

```
int seed = System.nanoTime();
boolean flags = new boolean[10];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int tmp = seed;
while(tmp > 0) {
   int digit = tmp % 10;
   if(!flags[digit]) {
       sb.append(digit);
       flags[digit] = true;
   }
   tmp /= 10;
}
```

Как-то так. нужно добавить ограничение на длину результата и повтор если символов меньше.

**EDIT** Версия без использования `StringBuilder`

```
int seed = System.nanoTime();
boolean flags = new boolean[10];
int result = 0;
int count = 0;
int tmp = seed;
while(tmp > 0) {
   int digit = tmp % 10;
   if(!flags[digit]) {
       result *= 10;
       result += digit;
       flags[digit] = true;
       count++;
       if(count == maxCount) {
           break;
       }
   }
   tmp /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно это сделать проще? Дело в том, что это задание с сайта по изучению java и, если совсем уж строго подходить, должно выполняться с учетом того, что сейчас пройдены только такие темы как: переменные, ветвления, циклы, простые массивы.

Comment: Так я ничего кроме перечисленного и не использую.

Comment: Вот этот класс, например - StringBuilder();, без него можно?

Comment: @АлександрКочнев Добавил версию без `StringBuilder`

Comment: Спасибо большое!